# Does radiation pressure affects cavity lenght of laser?

Tags: laser, quantum-optics

In a simple laser cavity two mirrors reflect light creating standing waves. Light exchanges momentum creating radiation pressure on the mirror. This force accelerates mirrors, changing the cavity lenght. I was wondering if this effect is too low and can be ignored or in some cases can't be neglected. Does radiation pressure in the cavity contributes to fluctuations in a laser?